# MKMapRect zooms too much

Tags: iphone, xcode

I use this code to show all my annotations on my map:

```
 MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations)
        {
            MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 1000);
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
                zoomRect = pointRect;
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
            }
        }
        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

But my problem is that when the annotations are close to each other, it zooms too much as the rectangle is small.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
//here comes your for loop...

double minMapHeight = 10; //choose some value that fit your needs
double minMapWidth = 10;  //the same as above
BOOL needChange = NO;

double x = MKMapRectGetMinX(zoomRect);
double y = MKMapRectGetMinY(zoomRect);
double w = MKMapRectGetWidth(zoomRect);
double h = MKMapRectGetHeight(zoomRect);  //here was an error!!

if(MKMapRectGetHeight(zoomRect) < minMapHeight){
    x -= minMapWidth/2;
    w += minMapWidth/2;
    needChange = YES;
}
if(MKMapRectGetWidth(zoomRect) < minMapWidth){
    y -= minMapHeight/2;
    h += minMapHeight/2;
    needChange = YES;
}
if(needChange){
    zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

### EDITED ->

```
double minMapHeight = 250; //choose some value that fit your needs
double minMapWidth = 250;  //the same as above
BOOL needChange = NO;

double x = MKMapRectGetMinX(zoomRect);
double y = MKMapRectGetMinY(zoomRect);
double w = MKMapRectGetWidth(zoomRect);
double h = MKMapRectGetHeight(zoomRect);
double centerX = MKMapRectGetMidX(zoomRect);
double centerY = MKMapRectGetMidY(zoomRect);

if(MKMapRectGetHeight(zoomRect) < minMapHeight){
    //x -= minMapWidth/2;
    //w += minMapWidth/2;
    x = centerX - w/2;
    needChange = YES;
}
if(MKMapRectGetWidth(zoomRect) < minMapWidth){
    //y -= minMapHeight/2;
    //h += minMapHeight/2;
    y = centerY - h/2;
    needChange = YES;
}
if(needChange){
    zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

Comment: I tried setting the variables to 200, but nothing happened. Then I sat it to 300 and it zoomed all the way out - way too much.

Comment: I've made an error in line where I declared h. Fixed it. Anyway, I'll add some more code for other possible answer

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me sadly. Maybe they have changed something in their APIs in newer iOS versions?

Comment: In the "Edited" section, the `minMapHeight` and `minMapWidth` variables only used for comparison and not actually factored into how the height/width are adjusted. This seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

In my code, I add extra spacing around, so it will automatically adjust the zoom level in order to fit.

```
[aMapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-100, -50, -50, -50) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Had to use positive edge insets in my case

Comment: Why negative Insets?

Comment: mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 50, 50, 50), animated: true) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Ariel's answer didn't work for me, but I made a few small changes to it and it's working great now (especially with maps with a single pin):

```
double minimumZoom = 6000; // for my purposes the width/height have same min zoom
BOOL needChange = NO;

double x = MKMapRectGetMinX(zoomRect);
double y = MKMapRectGetMinY(zoomRect);
double w = MKMapRectGetWidth(zoomRect);
double h = MKMapRectGetHeight(zoomRect);
double centerX = MKMapRectGetMidX(zoomRect);
double centerY = MKMapRectGetMidY(zoomRect);

if (h < minimumZoom) {  // no need to call MKMapRectGetHeight again; we just got its value!
    // get the multiplicative factor used to scale old height to new,
    // then apply it to the old width to get a proportionate new width
    double factor = minimumZoom / h;
    h = minimumZoom;
    w *= factor;
    x = centerX - w/2;
    y = centerY - h/2;
    needChange = YES;
}

if (w < minimumZoom) {
    // since we've already adjusted the width, there's a chance this
    // won't even need to execute
    double factor = minimumZoom / w;
    w = minimumZoom;
    h *= factor;
    x = centerX - w/2;
    y = centerY - h/2;
    needChange = YES;
}

if (needChange) {
    zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(x, y, w, h);
}

[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ariel's solution wasn't working for me either but n00neimp0rtant's was. I have rewritten it in Swift as a function `rectWithMinimumZoom(_ minimumZoom: Double)` in an extension of MKMapRect. In return it the adjusted rect (if adjustment is needed). Also I added a extra safety that minimumZoom cannot be divided by 0.

**SWIFT**

```
extension MKMapRect {
func rectWithMinimumZoom(_ minimumZoom: Double = 750) -> MKMapRect{
    var needChange = false

    var x = MKMapRectGetMinX(self)
    var y = MKMapRectGetMinY(self)
    var w = MKMapRectGetWidth(self)
    var h = MKMapRectGetHeight(self)
    let centerX = MKMapRectGetMidX(self)
    let centerY = MKMapRectGetMidY(self)

    if(h < minimumZoom){
        let factor = minimumZoom / max(h,1)
        h = minimumZoom
        w *= factor;
        x = centerX - w / 2
        y = centerY - h / 2
        needChange = true
    }
    if(w < minimumZoom){
        let factor = minimumZoom / max(w,1)
        w = minimumZoom
        h *= factor
        x = centerX - w / 2
        y = centerY - h / 2
        needChange = true
    }
    if(needChange){
        return MKMapRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    }
    return self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who like one liners:

```
let minRectSize: Double = 5000
zoomRect = MKMapRect(
    x: zoomRect.minX - max(0, minRectSize - zoomRect.width) / 2,
    y: zoomRect.minY - max(0, minRectSize - zoomRect.height) / 2,
    width: max(zoomRect.width, minRectSize),
    height: max(zoomRect.height, minRectSize))
```