# Zoom MKMapView to fit polyline points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, cllocation

I have an array, allCollections, that holds programmatically-created arrays of CLLocations the user has recorded through my iOS app. Each sub-array in allCollections holds all the location points in a trip taken.

I draw MKPolylines off of the CLLocations in the arrays in allCollections to represent those trips on an MKMapView. My question is this: With the polylines added to the map, how would I go about programmatically zooming and centering the map to display all of them?

Answer (score 71):

```
-(void)zoomToPolyLine: (MKMapView*)map polyline: (MKPolyline*)polyline animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    [map setVisibleMapRect:[polyline boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0) animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: @BradKoch This solution uses `boundingMapRect` to define a rectangle that encompasses the polyline overlay. It then sets the map zoom area to that rectangle with `setVisibleMapRect` taking into account the adjustable padding values with `edgePadding`. I found this solution to be the most helpful, since it solves the problem efficiently with few lines of code and also allows for changes to the map view area through insets.

Comment: This works for me. But apparently this sets the zoom factor to **fill** the screen, instead of **fit**. Can you think of a solution for that

Comment: Plus one for a solution with insets.

Comment: Good solution +1. Only thing is that Padding needs to be adjusted as per visual needs, that way it will support all the other overlays.

Answer (score 15):

```
-(void)zoomToPolyLine: (MKMapView*)map polyLine: (MKPolyline*)polyLine 
animated (BOOL)animated
{
MKPolygon* polygon = 
    [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:polyLine.points count:polyLine.pointCount];

[map setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([polygon boundingMapRect]) 
     animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: It is not required to create a MKPolygon as MKPolyline already implement boundingMapRect

Comment: how are you assigning fence to CLLocation ?? means in goefencing how to you allocate that CLregion instead of circular region???

Answer (score 15):

in swift:

```
if let first = mapView.overlays.first {
    let rect = mapView.overlays.reduce(first.boundingMapRect, combine: {MKMapRectUnion($0, $1.boundingMapRect)})
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
}
```

this will zoom/pan to fit all overlays with a little buffer

Answer (score 10):

You could loop through all `CLLocations` recording the `max/min` coordinates and use that to set a view rect like they do on this question [iOS MKMapView zoom to show all markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434020/mkmapview-zoom-to-bounds-with-multiple-markers) .

Or you could go through each of your overlays and get their `boundingMapRect` then use `MKMapRectUnion` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKMapRectUnion) to combine them all until you have one `MKMapRect` that covers them all and use that to set the view.

```
[mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES]
```

This question shows a simple loop combining the maprects in unions as I suggested: [MKMapRect zooms too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465149/mkmaprect-zooms-too-much)

Comment: I owe you a beer for that :)

Comment: MKMapRectUnion link is broken, here's the new page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/1452123-mkmaprectunion

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3** version of garafajon excellent code

```
    if let first = self.mapView.overlays.first {
        let rect = self.mapView.overlays.reduce(first.boundingMapRect, {MKMapRectUnion($0, $1.boundingMapRect)})
        self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Swift 5 version: the second line of code from above changes a bit:
 let rect = self.mapView.overlays.reduce(first.boundingMapRect, {$0.union($1.boundingMapRect)})
    
        }

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4 / slightly modified version of fundtimer's answer.

```
 func setVisibleMapArea(polyline: MKPolyline, edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets, animated: Bool = false) {
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: edgeInsets, animated: animated)
}
```

Calling the above using a route's polyline and leaving the default of not animated, and adding small edge insets of 10 all around:

```
setVisibleMapArea(polyline: route.polyline, edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0))
```

Comment: A simple solution - nice!

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution for this problem

```
private func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion? {


    let latitudes = self.coordinates.map { location -> Double in

        return location.latitude
    }

    let longitudes = self.coordinates.map { location -> Double in

        return location.longitude
    }

    let maxLat = latitudes.max()!
    let minLat = latitudes.min()!
    let maxLong = longitudes.max()!
    let minLong = longitudes.min()!

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (minLat + maxLat) / 2,
                                        longitude: (minLong + maxLong) / 2)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (maxLat - minLat) * 1.3,
                                longitudeDelta: (maxLong - minLong) * 1.3)
    return MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
}
```

Where coordinates is Array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

Hope it is helpful to someone

Answer (score 0):

@Fundtimer pointed it right way, Only thing is that Padding needs to be adjusted as per visual needs, that way it will support all the other overlays and following is the generic solution for all overlays.

```
-(void)zoomIntoExistingMapObjectForAnnot:(CustomMapAnnotation *)annot
{
   id overlay = annot.shape;//I have overlay property in custom annotation class.
   [_mapView setVisibleMapRect:[overlay boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(150.0, 150.0, 150.0, 150.0) animated:YES];
}
```