# Centring a route between two destinations on a MapView

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I would like to know how to centre a route on a MapView. Or how to calculate the center to ensure that both points are also visible on the mapview?

At present I use the `setRegion` method with some custom calculations to work out the zoom.

```
[_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
```

I see that I can also use `setVisibleMapRect: edgePadding: animated:` but I am not sure how to get a MKMapRect for use.

---

I find the address of a business with `geocodeAddressString` then have a `CLPlaceMark` result.
I have an `MKPointAnnotation` which is the pin for the destination (business).
I then create a `MKDirectionRequest` to an `MKPlaceMark` created from the `CLPlaceMark`. I then display the route.

How do I zoom in to a specific amount based on this workflow, so that I could get a result like these below. Specifically where the route is centered in the mapView and both user location and the annotation are shown on screen without being miles/very far out?

[image][image][image]

Comment: The directions request returns polyline(s).  You can use the boundingMapRect of the polyline(s) as the parameter to setVisibleMapRect.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799887/setregion-to-encapsulate-route.

Comment: Thanks are you marking as dup or submitting as an answer, this worked great for me