# How can I expand a MKMapRect by a fixed percentage?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I want to get a result MKMapRect that's 10-20% larger in all directions than the current `visibleMapRect`. If this were a CGRect I'd use CGRectInset with negative x and y values, providing me with an inverse inset (i.e. a larger rect). Unfortunately, MKMapInset doesn't support negative inset values so it's not quite that easy.

This might be easier if the the values for the map rect were recognizable units but the origin x and y values are on the order of 4.29445e+07, and the width/height is 2500-3000.

I'm about 10 seconds from writing a category to do this manually but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something first. Is there an easier way to expand MKMapRect?

Comment: This help you at all? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465149/mkmaprect-zooms-too-much

Comment: note, for 2017 Apple have now **done all the work**, see answer below

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In iOS7, `rectForMapRect:` and `mapRectForRect:` has been deprecated and now are part of the `MKOverlayRenderer` class. I'd rather recommend to use the `MapView` `mapRectThatFits: edgePadding:` methods. Here is a sample code :

```
MKMapRect visibleRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
MKMapRect biggerRect = [self.mapView mapRectThatFits:visibleRect edgePadding:insets];
```

latest Swift for 2017...

```
func updateMap() {

    mkMap.removeAnnotations(mkMap.annotations)
    mkMap.addAnnotations(yourAnnotationsArray)

    var union = MKMapRectNull

    for p in yourAnnotationsArray {
        // make a small, say, 50meter square for each
        let pReg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( pa.coordinate, 50, 50 )
        // convert it to a MKMapRect
        let r = mkMapRect(forMKCoordinateRegion: pReg)

        // union all of those
        union = MKMapRectUnion(union, r)

        // probably want to turn on the "sign" for each
        mkMap.selectAnnotation(pa, animated: false)
    }

    // expand the union, using the new #edgePadding call. T,L,B,R
    let f = mkMap.mapRectThatFits(union, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 10, 35))

    // NOTE you want the TOP padding much bigger than the BOTTOM padding
    // because the pins/signs are actually very tall

    mkMap.setVisibleMapRect(f, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: great answer. user, I threw in the latest syntax for that call, feel free to edit etc. cheers.

Answer (score 5):

What about converting the `visibleMapRect` to a `CGRect` with `rectForMapRect:`, getting a new `CGRect` with `CGRectInset` and then converting it back to a `MKMapRect` with `mapRectForRect:`?

Comment: this is actually incorrect now, 2017.  Apple have, thank goodness, done all the work now. **mapRectThatFits#edgePadding**

Answer (score 2):

Simple and clean solution for **Xcode 10+, Swift 4.2**

Just set the **edge insets** for the maps' margins like this:

```swift
self.mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8, left: 8)
self.mapView.showAnnotations(map.annotations, animated: true)
```

Please let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Refined and corrected [user2285781's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307286/347339) for Swift 4:

```
    // reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15683034/347339
    func MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region:MKCoordinateRegion) -> MKMapRect {
        let topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))
        let bottomRight = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: region.center.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta/2), longitude: region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta/2))

        let a = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
        let b = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)

        return MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(x:min(a.x,b.x), y:min(a.y,b.y)), size: MKMapSize(width: abs(a.x-b.x), height: abs(a.y-b.y)))
    }

    // reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307286/347339
    // assuming coordinates that create a polyline as well as a destination annotation
    func updateMap(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], annotation: MKAnnotation) {

        var union = MKMapRectNull
        var coordinateArray = coordinates
        coordinateArray.append(annotation.coordinate)

        for coordinate in coordinateArray {
            // make a small, say, 50meter square for each
            let pReg = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance( coordinate, 50, 50 )
            // convert it to a MKMapRect
            let r = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region: pReg)

            // union all of those
            union = MKMapRectUnion(union, r)
        }

        // expand the union, using the new #edgePadding call. T,L,B,R
        let f = mapView.mapRectThatFits(union, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 35, 10, 35))

        // NOTE you want the TOP padding much bigger than the BOTTOM padding
        // because the pins/signs are actually very tall

        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(f, animated: false)
    }
```